# Synchronously write file

Tags: java, c, programming-practices

I am implementing a server in C for a course project. The server should serve more than one client simultaneously. The description of the project states that `fork()` should be used to serve more than one client. Each children should write something to a common file. How do I handle this synchronously? Is there any mechanism like in Java where only one thread can use a function at the same time?

Comment: Have a look at, say, logging in Apache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're using `fork()`, you are spawning new processes, not new threads. That means you can't synchronize via monitors. You can, however, synchronize via [named semaphores](http://linux.die.net/man/7/sem_overview).